# Tomcat: Cannot put items on the request queue

Tags: java, coldfusion, tomcat8, lucee

We have a Java application running on Tomcat (8.0.32) that intermittently stops processing requests. The CPU is doing very little and a thread dump shows not a lot of running threads and a larger number of threads that are WAITING (mostly looks like queued threads in Tomcat).

It seems to me that the Tomcat workers and client pollers have become stuck, but it is quite possible/likely that I am misreading the thread dump. I have a clientPoller that appears to be waiting for a lock while offering a connection into the queue. The same lock is blocking any of the workers from picking up anything from the queue. We cannot see any threads *causing* the lock. Below is stack trace of the ClientPoller + one worker (many workers with identical stack trace):

```
"http-nio-8888-ClientPoller-1" #42 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007efc9cb86800 nid=0x3367 waiting on condition [0x00007efc5f5f4000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000821e3940> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:870)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1199)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:209)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:285)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.signalNotEmpty(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.offer(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:430)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.offer(TaskQueue.java:74)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.offer(TaskQueue.java:31)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1361)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:141)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.processSocket(AbstractEndpoint.java:934)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Poller.processKey(NioEndpoint.java:834)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Poller.run(NioEndpoint.java:810)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

```
"http-nio-8888-exec-1" #46 daemon prio=1 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007efbb8002000 nid=0x336a waiting on condition [0x00007efc5f2f1000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000821e3940> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:870)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2083)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.poll(TaskQueue.java:85)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.poll(TaskQueue.java:31)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Questions:

- Is the situation with the ClientPoller-1 actually normal? Or does it indicate a problem? To me it looks like it is stuck when announcing the the queue is not empty.
- Does this scenario ring any bells?

Happy to upload the entire thread dump if necessary and provide any other information.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat 8.0.x is no longer supported. If it isn't already on your TODO list you should add upgrading to 8.5.x or 9.0.x - ideally the latest available release of either.

Best guess would be a OutOfMemoryError killing a thread whilst it was holding the lock those other threads are waiting for. In theory the lock should have been released but once an OOME occurs nothing is guaranteed. I'd check your logs for an OOME some time before this issue occurred. If it was an OOME, you might want to run a profiler to check on memory usage over time in case your application needs a larger heap.

Comment: Thanks Mark, that sounds plausible. Are you aware of any other thread errors other than OOME that cause a similar behaviour (will check, but memory usage seems pretty stable).